# Disable Alt+Enter for TreeViewer in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, swt, workbench

I have added a key listener to a tree in SWT and when i press Alt+Enter the state of the key event is keyCode = 65536 and statemask = 0, when it should have been keyCode='\r' and statemask=65536.
Below is the code snippet i have written-

```
mViewer.getTree().addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                if(e.keyCode == SWT.CR && e.stateMask == SWT.ALT) {
                    e.doit = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Eclipse workbench filters some of the events before delegating the events to the listeners in the components. Is there a way i can disable the alt+enter to not execute the show properties in eclipse on one of the treeviewers?

Best Regards,
Keshav

Comment: Haven't you changed the description quite a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override a specific global command for a specific Viewer is many different ways:

- Add a listener to filter out the key sequence - though not always possible.
- Add a `Display` filter to do the same - the filter can be added/removed at the focus in/out on the control of the Viewer.
- Add a new context to the application and override the needed key bindings for the new context - the context is activated/deactivated at the focus in/out on the control of the Viewer

I prefer this last solution as I can override specific key bindings for the Viewer from any plug-in using the normal binding extension point...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
mViewer.getTree().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.CR && e.stateMask == SWT.ALT) {
            // your code
            e.doit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

And the imports you need:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
```

Comment: Could you try and debug the event? Does the event even get called? What are the values? etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will see all the key/down events - even if the key is a state key. So the first event is for the `Alt` key down...

The sequence should be:

- KeyDown: stateMask=0 and keyCode=65536
- KeyDown: stateMask=65536 and keyCode='\r'
- KeyUp: stateMask=65536 and keyCode='\r'
- KeyUp: stateMask=0 and keyCode=65536

Comment: i forgot to mention that this is in eclipse workbench and it seems that the workbench filters some of the events before delegating the events to the listeners in the component. Is there a way i can disable these filtering on the component i want?

Comment: You can use `Display.addFilter(...)` instead of `Control.addListener(...)`. That does guarantee that you see all events, but these may be modified, as a prior filter can modify the event as it like - most often set `event.type = SWT.None` or `event.doit = false`, though other changes are possible - and legal - too... I have used this in a number of cases to fix peculialities in the different SWT implementations.

Comment: And of cause, for completeness I should mention that the operating system is free to eat whatever events - especially key event - as it pleases. E.g. Alt-Ctl-Del under Windows and F9 under OSX.